# OSM - Mapnik - areas rendered as background color

Tags: openstreetmap, postgis, mapnik

I am generating maps using Mapnik and OSM data (postgres and shapefiles).  My problem is that quite a few areas, most of which I believe are considered "landcover", are rendering as the background color.  The areas render as background color regardless of zoom level.

For example, in between streets, everything is blue.  There are some forests that render as expected, but most of the residential areas are just blue.

I am using Mapnik 3 with a stylesheet.  This is running on Ubuntu 16.04.

The images below show what I am generating, and what I would like to see (based on what is on Openstreetmaps).

Any suggestions as to where I should look to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

[What I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xAaJ.png)

[OSM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QtKH.png)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by some invalid zoom levels and/or MinScaleDenominator, MaxScaleDenominator values.  I have not narrowed it down completely, but by removing those attributes, I'm seeing the land again.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Fixing the problem was done by two things:
1.  Replacing the builtup_areas.shp file with world_boundaries_m.shp
2.  Removing the Min and Max ScaleDenominator attributes.
I"ll probably adjust the min and max scale denominator attributes, but removing them solves the problem.  

Thank you for pointing me to the stylesheet!

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue with your stylesheet, if it's a custom one I recommend loading it into TileMill and playing around the LandCover and Area colours until you're satisfied.

If you were wanting a relevant point of reference, check out the **Stylesheet Configuration** to get your own copy of OSMBright, so you can compare the rendering styles.

**Update** A link for the OSM style look: https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto

Comment: Hi, I appreciate the fast response, but I think I may be overlooking something.  I downloaded the carto files, generated the style sheet using carto, and replaced my current style sheet that, but I'm still just seeing the background color.  Did I  miss a step?

Comment: did you restart the tile server so that it uses the new stylesheet?

Comment: Another side issue that I ran into (not related but worth the time): make sure you have all the dependency fonts that the stylesheet is referencing.

Comment: I'm using tilecache with openlayers (I should have probably mentioned that).  I deleted the tilecache and re-generated the tiles.  At first I got errors because I didn't copy the symbols, so it seems to be using the new style sheet.